# R - Mean of two variables containing NA

Tags: r, na

I am new to R and I have a question that is probably very simple.

I want to calculate a mean value from two variables. If one variable has a missing value, the vector with the mean values should take the value of the available variable. Are there any tips?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  Perhaps, you need `rowMeans(cbind(v1, v2), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Jep, that's it! Do you know what do to with NaN values resulting of both variables being NA (missing) ?

Comment: What is your expected for that  case i.e. when both elements have `NA` at the same position

Comment: that the mean is also NA

Comment: Please check my solution.  I updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rowMeans` after `cbind`ing the two vectors

```
out <- rowMeans(cbind(v1, v2), na.rm = TRUE)
out[is.nan(out)] <- NA
out
#[1] 3.0 3.0  NA 2.5 5.0
```

Or we can use `replace_na` (which also would match the `NaN`

```
library(dplyr)
replace_na(rowMeans(cbind(v1, v2), na.rm = TRUE), NA)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 3, NA, 2, NA)
v2 <- c(5, NA, NA, 3, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

So R mean function can handle this behavior automatically by setting `na.rm = TRUE.`

```
var1 <- 4
var2 <- 2

mean(c(var1, var2), na.rm = TRUE)
# 3

var1 <- 2
var2 <- NA
mean(c(var1, var2), na.rm = TRUE)
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a reproducible example as per @akrun's comment. However, I hope this helps you somehow.

Given two variables, could be in a data frame or not, `ab` and `ac`, you can do:

```
> ab
[1]  1  3  4  6  7 NA

> ac
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8 10

> ifelse(sum(is.na(ab)) >= 1, mean(ac), mean(ab))
[1] 6.142857
```

Comment: Better use `anyNA(ab)`